# Why I Cannot See"Find And Replace" Window

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am using VS 2015 Update 3 on Windows 10, previously all is fine, in about one week ago, I found Ctr+Shift+F not working and I tried to click the menu item "Find In Files" as well, still not working. I also tried use devenv /resetsettings, the issue did not gone. I also tried reinstall VS 2015. The issue still persists.

Actually the issue is weird, whenever in a new launch of VS2015, that combination key works for the first time when you search. After that the "Find And Replace" window does not come again when you press the combination key.

Have anybody met this issue? Looking for help.

Comment: Have you gone on the Window menu and chosen Reset Window Layout? Sometimes my ctrl f appears docked in another window, not necessarily the one I was expected. Have you tried "using it" even though you can't see it? It would prove if it's open on screen somewhere.  Some generic advice whenever I can't see any window(not just find in files) but in particular the Find in Files: press ESC a few times, press ctrl shift f, press alt space, press m, press any cursor key, move the mouse, left click

Comment: Have you tried a newer version of VS?  VS 2019?

Comment: this issue still exists, not solved.